# Medsphere chart widget: how to display a simple chart?

Tags: gtk, gtk#

i've found this interesting [widget](http://medsphere.org/community/project/medsphere-widgets) and in particular i'm interested in display chart. 
The problem is i can't find how to. Does anyone know this widget and know how to show a simple chart, and finally, post an example here  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the graph demo [here](https://medsphere.org:8443/svn/widgets/trunk/demo/GraphDemo.cs). In particular, most of the time you instantiate a `Graph2D` object, add the necessary X and Y axes (usually `LinearAxis` which implements `IAxis`) and then add whatever `IPlot` instances you want to be shown on the graph (e.g. a `LinePlot` or `HistogramPlot`)

You can look at the AddRandomLinePlot method in that demo to see that in action.

Answer (score 0):

all    I assume that you have aready download [Medsphere.Widgets](http://medsphere.org/community/project/medsphere-widgets?view=overview),and build successfully and get Medsphere.Widgets.dll.

---

First ,you should create a new GTK# project.   Secondly,  add the GraphDemo.cs which is in the Demo files into your solution. And modify the GraphDemo's constructor: modify" public GraphDemo ():base("Graph Demo")"into  " public GraphDemo (Mainwindow window):base("Graph Demo")".   Thirdly,edit your Main(string[] args) like this:

```
public static viod Main()
        {
          Application.Init();
          MainWindow testWindow=new MainWindow();
          GraphDemo testGD=new GraphDemo(testWindow);//this is key.
          testWindow.ShowAll();
          Application.Run();
          }

       fellow these steps, you can get the beautiful chart.
```

Hope this can help you,look forward to receive your feeback.

yours, 
  Demi